# ayuda con React native: Failed building JavaScript bundle / Restarted watchman

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Buenas tardes, Estoy empezando con React native y me surgió de la nada un problema que ya no me deja hacer nada, simplemente en la terminal cada que doy reload a la aplicación me dice "Failed building JavaScript bundle" y en la siguiente linea "Restarted watchman", ya reinstalé watchman con home brew (Mac), lo eliminé y los volví a instalar de cero y ya no puedo trabajar ningún proyecto, alguien me puede ayudar?
De antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

intenta con esto:

> npm start -- --reset-cache
>   Ó
>   yarn start -- --reset-cache

y si no ._. pues reboot a tu pc xD

Comment: Hola Bruno, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio). Estoy revisando las respuestas marcadas como de baja calidad y me estoy encontrando con varias tuyas. Muchas de ellas parecen más comentarios que respuestas en sí, y a otras les falta información importante (por ejemplo en ésta: ¿qué hacen los comandos especificados? ¿por qué funcionarían?). Lee [ask] y revisa tus publicaciones para mejorarlas con las recomendaciones que encontrarás en ese artículo.